# How can I dump internal storage of formatted Poco X3 Pro for video and image recovery - or any other available method

Tags: data-recovery

I have accidentally formatted my Poco X3 Pro when it was stuck in a bootloop due to power button problem. It was thinking power button was pressed.

I did RMA it, fixed and received the phone today

So what are my options to recover image and video files that were on the internal storage?

Currently phone is locked and I will be able to unlock it in 7 days

Can you list my options currently available and after unlocking and if necessary rooting it

I can wait 7 days before using the phone

I really want to recovery as many as possible images and videos which are my baby daughter photos and videos

By the way I use windows. I have already installed ADB and drivers. ADB works but I can't see the device in the connected devices list

Thank you

Comment: By formatted you mean factory reset? If yes then all your data is gone. Your phone as are leased 2021 with Android 11 which means it uses File Based Encryption for all user data. A factory reset erases the used encryption keys which makes all data unrecoverable.

Comment: @Robert yes factory reset. Then I shouldn't waste time to recover any?

Comment: If the implementation by Poco is correct there should be no chance to recover anything.

Comment: you can only recover what is in [mi cloud](https://i.mi.com) or [google cloud](https://photos.google.com)

Comment: @Robert alecxs ty for replies